# Proof that $L^1(\mu)\cong L^1([0,1])$ for a probability measure $\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, banach-spaces

A classical result of functional analysis states that the space $L^1(K, \mu)$, $\mu$ a nonatomic probability measure on a separable metric space $K$, is isometric to $L^1([0,1])$. The key ingredient for this is the existence of a bijection $\sigma\colon K\to[0,1]$ with the additional properties that $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ are both Borel maps and that $\mu(B) = \lambda(\sigma^{-1}(B))$ for every Borel set $B\subset K$.

I am interested both in a reference to the standard proof of this result as well as a reference to the "original" proof in case it is known who gave the first proof of this result.

Comment: Not true as stated.  You certainly need $\mu$ to be nonatomic.

Comment: See [standard probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space).  The result is basically due to von Neumann and Rokhlin.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks, I added that $\mu$ should be nonatomic

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for mentioning "standard probability space". I was only looking for the result in Banach space theory books and there I did not see this term.